# Terminology queries

Tags: terminology, movements

I'm new to music and just getting to know the terms, so I read a bit on sites like wikipedia and watched some videos, but I still find hard to answer the following things about Copland's 1938 Billy the Kid:

1. Why is it called a Suite? Is it because there are no stops in between its parts?
2. Is that a single movement piece?
3. How can one divide its nuances?

Comment: What does it mean to "divide a nuance"? Are you asking how could/should one break the piece into smaller sections to better understand and analyze it?

Comment: Exactly, TW, that was my idea.

Answer (score 2):

"Suite" is a traditional name for a collection of pieces, each in a different dance style.  Bach used Allamande, Bouree, Minuet....   It's also often used for a concert selection of excerpts from a ballet e.g. Tchaikovsky's Swan Lake Suite. Whether there is an appreciable pause between sections is unimportant, the point is that there ARE clearly-defined sections.  If the tunes were combined more freely, a title such as "Rhapsody on themes from Billy the Kid" might be more appropriate.  I don't think you'll have any trouble hearing (and seeing in the score) where one section ends, another begins!

Comment: That's one part of the definition.  The Suite in this case is a collection of **excerpts** from the full ballet.  Usually the music is titled  "Suite from Ballet XXXX"  (many Stravinsky ballets had suites generated for things like pops concerts).